# Saving variable size part of string to another variable

Tags: python, string, variables, url

I am messing around with string on an imageboard, and I want to be able to grab the board name from the end of the URL. I was wondering if I could possibly use %s to save it to another variable, but I only know how to use that to assign. Here is an example of the end of the URL.

```
url = '/a/thread/144681013/'

board = #Where I want to save the 'a'
```

I can't just say it's at position `url[1]`, because the board could be more than 1 letter, like:

```
url = '/fdf/thread/144681013/'

board = #Where I want to save the 'fdf'
```

I can't find an example in documentation anywhere, is there any placeholder I could put in the board that would automatically extract the board part of the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just [split your string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) at the `/` characters and grab the second element of the resulting list (the first one is empty because of the leading `/`)

```
board = url.split('/')[1]
```

You could also use regular expressions if you wanted.

```
import re
board = re.search('(?<=^\/).*?(?=\/)', url).group()
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!